# I don't understand the Pseudocode APCSP

Tags: pseudocode

[image: Pseudocode]

I partially understand what the question is asking but why are all answer choices not right?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking but the first and third examples are correct.

Answer (score 1):

We could write this as a truth table.

The initial statement is `x = a AND (NOT b)`

So...

```
a b | x
-------
0 0 | 0
1 0 | 1
0 1 | 0
1 1 | 0
```

In each of the examples you have...

1.

```
a b | x
-------
0 0 | 0
1 0 | 1
0 1 | 0
1 1 | 0
```

2. 

```
a b | x
-------
0 0 | 1
1 0 | 1
0 1 | 0
1 1 | 1
```

3. 

```
a b | x
-------
0 0 | 0
1 0 | 1
0 1 | 0
1 1 | 0
```

4. 

```
a b | x
-------
0 0 | 1
1 0 | 1
0 1 | 0
1 1 | 1
```

I'll leave it to you to work out why all those are like that but that should show you why they are not all correct.